# How can I use MotionLayout to hide/show views only when scrolling a RecyclerView that is too big for the screen?

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-motionlayout, android-motionscene

I have a `Fragment` which is used to make searches. Its layout has a "search bar" at the top, and then there is a `TextView` and a `RecyclerView` where I display the results. I would like to hide/show the search bar and the `TextView` when user scrolls, like in this [video](https://youtu.be/d-ek7YpvAGU), but instead of hiding the `Toolbar` my idea is to hide the search bar and the `TextView`. Something like this:

[image: Expected result]

I already have a custom `Toolbar` in the `activity_main.xml` that must be fixed across the activity, only the search bar and the `TextView` needs to be hidden/shown.

I tried to get it working using `CoordinatorLayout`, but all examples I found were to show/hide the `Toolbar`, hence I am not really sure if I can get what I want using `CoordinatorLayout`.

After multiple attempts with `CoordinatorLayout`, I decided to look for another solution and found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48961712/21021740). However, it does not work like in the sample. First of all, it breaks part of my code functionallity, and secondly altough the search bar and `TextView` are hidden/shown, the `RecyclerView` keeps it position instead of take the place of the other two views:

[image: Search bar and TextViews are hidden but RecyclerView do not take their place]

Finally, looking for more solutions I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57327651/21021740) that uses `MotionLayout`. It works great except for one problem. When the `RecyclerView` is empty, its `visibility` is `GONE` or the number of items to display can fit in the space available of the screen, the user can still scroll and hide the search bar and the `TextView`:

[image: User can scroll even if there is nothing else to show]

I don't expect this behaviour, I expect the views to collapse only when the `RecyclerView` is too big for the screen. How can achieve this?

I have been struggling with this the last couple of days and cannot find a solution, I hope you can help me. Find below the XML files. Thank you in advance!

Activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <!-- Contenedor principal para mostrar el Toolbar y el contenido oportuno-->
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <!-- Toolbar que hace de ActionBar -->
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
        
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <!-- Menú para moverse por la app -->
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    motion:layoutDescription="@xml/motionscene"
    tools:context=".SearchFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buscador"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/cyan"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/num_resultados">

        <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/search_view_background"
            android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"
            android:queryHint="Buscar..." />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/filtro_busqueda"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/nom_futbolistico_Rb"
                style="@style/SearchRadioButton"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="@string/nombre_futbolistico" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/nombre_Rb"
                style="@style/SearchRadioButton"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
                android:text="@string/nombre" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/apellidos_Rb"
                style="@style/SearchRadioButton"
                android:text="@string/apellidos" />
        </RadioGroup>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/num_resultados"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/recycler_view_item_search"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingVertical="8dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:visibility="gone"
        motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/buscador" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/lista_deportistas_Rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/num_resultados"
        tools:listitem="@layout/listado_deportista_item" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

MotionScene:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@id/recogido"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/expandido">

        <OnSwipe
            motion:dragDirection="dragUp"
            motion:moveWhenScrollAtTop="false"
            motion:touchAnchorId="@id/lista_deportistas_Rv"
            motion:touchAnchorSide="top" />

    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/expandido">
        <Constraint android:id="@id/buscador" >
            <PropertySet android:alpha="1" />
        </Constraint>
        <Constraint android:id="@id/num_resultados">
            <PropertySet android:alpha="1"
                motion:visibilityMode="ignore"/>
        </Constraint>
        <Constraint android:id="@id/lista_deportistas_Rv">
            <PropertySet motion:visibilityMode="ignore"/>
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/recogido">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/buscador"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent">
            <PropertySet android:alpha="0" />
        </Constraint>
        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/num_resultados"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            motion:visibilityMode="ignore"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent">
            <PropertySet android:alpha="0" />
        </Constraint>
        <Constraint android:id="@id/lista_deportistas_Rv">
            <PropertySet motion:visibilityMode="ignore"/>
        </Constraint>

    </ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```

Comment: There are several issues with your motionSceen. 
Take a look at the examples in: https://github.com/androidx/constraintlayout/tree/main/demoProjects/ExamplesRecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

This view hierarchy helped me achieve such behavior

```
    <LinearLayout>
            
                <CustomToolBarView /> (always visible view, something like Toolbar)
            
                <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
            
                    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
                         put here your hidebale views, add to all of them :
                            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                        
                    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
            
                    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        
                        put this attribute here:
                 
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior" />
        
                    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView/>
            
                </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
     <LinearLayout>
```